# Folder with URI 'tcm:3-11-196672' does not exist

Tags: 2013, audience-manager

When i open my Tridion 2013SP1HR1 CME , getting following error on few publications and doesnt display the contents from those publication:

> "Folder with URI 'tcm:3-11-196672' does not exist  at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.FolderDal.Read(Folder
>   folder)    at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Folder.Load()
>   at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.PublicationDal.Read(Publication
>   publication)    at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Publication.Load()    at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.AddOeRootNode(XmlTextReader
>   reader, TcmUri publicationUri)    at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.PostProcessListPublication(XmlTextReader
>   reader, TcmUri publicationUri, PipelineContext context)    at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.ProcessListResponse(XmlTextReader
>   reader, PipelineContext context)    at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader
>   reader, PipelineContext context)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(DataExtender
>   extender)    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1
>   action)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader
>   reader, PipelineContext context)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderParameterInspector.AfterCall(String
>   operationName, Object[] outputs, Object& returnValue, Object
>   correlationState)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)"

Could you pls share your inputs on what could be the problem here?

I have ensured that Audience Manager database is up and running.

Comment: How did you get here? The error indicates that there is a serious mismatch between the CM database and the AM one. Which doesn't happen during normal operations, but usually only if someone restores one database but not the other one.

Comment: Not sure, how did that mismatch happen :( Currently i resolved the issue by creating fresh Audience Manager database!

Comment: I sure hope you weren't actually using Audience Manager then! :) Anyway, I've added an answer so that this question isn't left "unanswered"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you have a mismatch between your Content Manager and Audience Manager databases. The AM database refers to items in the CM database and thus is dependent on it.

They will typically always be a sync. But it's possible that someone restored a backup of the CM database without also restoring the AM database -- or maybe someone restored the wrong version of the AM database.

Either way, the only way to resolve it is to make sure both databases are from the same time and matching each other. If you aren't actually using Audience Manager yet, you could simply create a fresh AM database too.